# Google Analytics: Ecommerce data not being sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to send events and ecommerce details in an AngularJS app. The event and pageviews are sending, however the ecommerce details won't went and I have no errors. Here is my setup:

An app.html with this:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    if (window.document.location.hostname == 'domain.com') {
        // Prod
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'auto');
    } else {
        // Dev
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    }

    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('require', 'ecommerce');
</script>
```

The conditional is just testing if it's on the production sive or the development site.

Here is the other part in one of my Angular controllers, triggered by the click of a button:

```
$scope.sendAnalyticsData = function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Click', 'Plan Enrollment Submitted');

        var id = $scope.id;
        var name = $scope.name;
        var sku = $scope.sku;
        var category = $scope.category;
        var price = $scope.price;

        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
            'id': id,
            'name': name,
            'sku': sku,
            'category': category,
            'price': price
        });

        ga('ecommerce:send');
    };
```

I just put some fake variables in there for these purposes.

When the button is clicked, that event is sent and I can see it on Analytics, however the ecommerce stuff is not sent. I've tried so many different variants including requireing 'ec' instead of 'ecommerce' and using the ec:addProduct variant. Nothing.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong in the ecommerce part?

Comment: Have you tried the analytics.js debugger? That will show you if there are any errors: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging

Comment: Have you checked that the addItem value hash isn't malformed in some way?  Non-null integer id, string name?  What do you see if you look at the web requests directly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that you are trying to add an item to nothing!  In this scenario, you need to create a transaction first and then add items to the transaction before sending the transaction and product data.

So, [taken from the google docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#addItem), add the transaction first:

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});
```

Then add your item(s)

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});
```

And finally submit your ecommerce data:

```
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

You'll obviously need to populate the fields correctly with your transaction data but this will give you a good template.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice! I reloaded Analytics this morning and everything I did yesterday all of a sudden populated. I guess ecommerce transactions are not instant like events and views? And in the docs they say if you don't make a transaction and only make an item, a transaction with the id of the item you make will be created by default. Thanks again!

Comment: ah yes, the old latency issue, forgot to ask about that.  thanks for noting the default transaction ID functionality - I wasn't aware of that! I'm sure that must be a recent addition, pretty certain it wasn't always the case.

Comment: Haha yeah! No worries, you taught me something and I taught you something :D!